# Change CSS of dynamic button on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a couple of buttons that are dynamically placed in an ng-repeat. I want to be able to "select" a button. By that I mean when I click on one, its CSS changes. When I click another one, the first button gets its original CSS back and the new button becomes selected. Can anyone help me out?

HTML:

```
<button ng-repeat="answer in regular_answers" ng-attr-id="{{'answer' + answer.regularAnswerId}}" class="button button-balanced button-block" ng-click="selectAnswer(answer)">
      {{answer.answer}}
</button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.selectAnswer = function (answer) {
    if (document.getElementById('answer' + answer.regularAnswerId).hasClass('button-selected')) {
      document.getElementById('answer' + answer.regularAnswerId).removeClass('button-selected');
      document.getElementById('answer' + answer.regularAnswerId).addClass('button-balanced');
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('answer' + answer.regularAnswerId).removeClass('button-balanced');
      document.getElementById('answer' + answer.regularAnswerId).addClass('button-selected');


    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to use a radio button group?  Hide the buttons, show only their labels, style the labels depending on whether their button is selected e.g. input[type=radio]:checked + label ... uses no JavaScript to control presentation, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use angular, the approach should be different, you don´t change the node after an event, instead, the node should respond to data changes:

```
<button ng-repeat="answer in regular_answers" class="button button-block" 
  ng-click="selectAnswer(answer)" 
  ng-class = "{buttonSelected:answer.regularAnswerId == selectedAnswer.regularAnswerId, 
             buttonBalanced: answer.regularAnswerId != selectedAnswer.regularAnswerId}">
      {{answer.answer}}
</button>
```

And then:

```
$scope.selectAnswer = function (answer) {
    $scope.selectedAnswer = answer;
}
```

See this example: http://codepen.io/sergio0983/pen/vyYNvy

**EDIT**

Added another pen with a different use case of ng-class that I think is a bit cleaner:

http://codepen.io/sergio0983/pen/VmweLP

```
<button ng-repeat="answer in regular_answers" 
 class="button button-block" 
 ng-click="selectAnswer(answer)" 
 ng-class = "answer.regularAnswerId == selectedAnswer.regularAnswerId ? 'button-selected' : 'button-balanced'">
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `ng-class` directive instead of doing DOM manipulation from controller(considered as bad pattern).

**Markup**

```
<button ng-repeat="answer in regular_answers" 
  ng-attr-id="{{'answer' + answer.regularAnswerId}}" 
  class="button" 
  ng-class="{'button-selected': answer.isSelcted, 'button-balanced': answer.isSelcted}"
  ng-click="answer.isSelected = !answer.isSelected">
      {{answer.answer}}
</button>
```

---

**PS:** 
For maintaining single Id you should preserve it inside a single scope variable.

```
<button ng-repeat="answer in regular_answers" 
  ng-attr-id="{{'answer' + answer.regularAnswerId}}" 
  class="button" 
  ng-class="{answer.regularAnswerId == selectedAnswerId ? 'button-selected': 'button-balanced'}"
  ng-click="selectAnswer(answer)">
      {{answer.answer}}
</button>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.selectAnswer = function(answer){
   $scope.selectedAnswerId = answer.regularAnswerId 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for selecting them, but it doesn't get deselected when a different one is selected?

Comment: @Ruben2112 take a look at updated answer now, Thanks ;)